# Why the results of Truecrypt and cryptsetup (LUKS) benchmarking are so different?

Tags: linux, truecrypt, disk-encryption, benchmarking, luks

I want to encrypt a part of my HDD. But before that I wanted to benchmark the different algorithm available wondering if I should choose `aes-xts-256` or `aes-xts-512`.

Note: I don't have `aes` hardware acceleration. The benchmarks were repeated multiple times without much change. I'd like to state clearly that these benchmark are only valid on my computer (Debian, core 2 duo). This is not intended to be a complete LUKS-TrueCrypt comparison.

**TL;DR:** go to part 4

---

## 1- Cryptsetup

So I downloaded `cryptsetup v1.6.0` to make use of the new `cryptsetup benchmark` command.

### Command

```
$cryptsetup benchmark
```

### Results

```
 #  Algorithm | Key | Encryption |  Decryption
     aes-cbc   128b   128,2 MiB/s   157,2 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   128b    49,6 MiB/s    57,7 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   128b   138,0 MiB/s   183,8 MiB/s
     aes-cbc   256b    97,5 MiB/s   121,9 MiB/s
 serpent-cbc   256b    51,8 MiB/s    57,7 MiB/s
 twofish-cbc   256b   139,0 MiB/s   183,8 MiB/s
     aes-xts   256b   156,4 MiB/s   157,8 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   256b    55,7 MiB/s    58,7 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   256b   161,5 MiB/s   165,9 MiB/s
     aes-xts   512b   120,5 MiB/s   120,9 MiB/s
 serpent-xts   512b    55,7 MiB/s    58,5 MiB/s
 twofish-xts   512b   161,5 MiB/s   165,3 MiB/s
```

### Thoughts

- <s>In `cbc` mode, `serpent` is surprisingly fast at decrypting!</s>
- <s>In `xts` mode, `serpent` is clearly the fastest.</s>
- The key size seem to have almost no noticable effect on <s>`serpent`</s> `twofish`.
- `aes` does not behave well when the key size is increased.

*Updates out of VM*

---

## 2- TrueCrypt

I was really surprised as `aes` is known to be the fastest (even without hardware acceleration). So I downloaded `TrueCrypt` to double-check these results. `TrueCrypt` uses the `xts` mode by default so I assume it also use it in its benchmarks.

### Method

> 1. Tools > Benchmark
> 2. Choose any buffer size (here, 5MB)
> 3. Click on "Benchmark"

### Results

```
 #  Algorithm | Encryption |  Decryption
         AES     106 MB/s      107 MB/s
     Twofish      78 MB/s       76 MB/s
     Serpent      41 MB/s       42 MB/s
```

### Thoughts

These results corresponds much more to what is expected but do not match well with `cryptsetup`'s results.

---

## 3- General thoughts

- `cryptsetup` provided better general performance than `TrueCrypt` in this case. This could be explained the following way:

  - `cryptsetup` was compiled on my system with compiler optimization routines while `TrueCrypt` was already compiled in a generic way;
  - AFAIK `cryptsetup` uses kernelspace crypto modules while `TrueCrypt` uses userspace crypto routines.
- However, I can't explain why `serpent-xts-512` seems to be the way to go with `cryptsetup` while `aes-xts` the only cipher worth using.

---

## 4- Question

`cryptsetup` and `TrueCrypt` give completely different qualitative (relative cipher speed) and quantitative (actual speed of each cipher) results in in-RAM benchmarks.

- Is that something you have already noticed?
- Should I trust `cryptsetup` and use `serpent-xts-512` cipher for speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have AES hardware acceleration, and were running the tests in a virtual machine.  It's unlikely that your test results would be reflective of real-world results, as the encryption/decryption speeds heavily depend on the current CPU & disk loads.  Your best bet is to create two independent Truecrypt partitions, and perform manual benchmarks by copying some large files to/from each partition.

LUKS and Truecrypt also have slightly different implementations, and as you said, "these benchmark are only valid on my computer".  You need to actually test both on your system with actual file transfers to determine the true performance.

---

As for the differences, Truecrypt uses [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) to implement a userspace filesystem, whereas [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) is usually done in the actual kernel.  For this reason, it's likely that you would get better throughput in a Linux system using LUKS/dm-crypt/cryptsetup as opposed to Truecrypt, although which option you choose depends on the requirements of your encryption (e.g. Truecrypt partitions can be transfered between operating systems if needed).

Comment: Strange: I tried directly in my system and basically everything stands excepts `serpent` which became much slower. So the problem with serpent is solved. `Twofish` is still faster than `aes` in `cryptsetup  ` and slower in `TrueCrypt`. And I don't have `aes` hardware acceleration at all... this is not a VM thing...

Comment: I updated the results.

Comment: @Gael `cryptsetup` will be faster than `TrueCrypt` given the same encryption algorithms since `TrueCrypt` runs under `FUSE` (user-space file system), whereas `cryptsetup` uses LUKS, which is a kernel module.  I mentioned the virtual machine as if you were running any other programs under your host OS (even background tasks), it would affect the results of your benchmarks.

Comment: This is no longer true. Cryptsetup now supports Veracrypt. I'm guessing there's a kernel module

Answer (score 1):

Linux kernel has SSE2 and AVX optimized Serpent modules to accelerate parallelizable workloads (such as CBC decryption and XTS enc&dec).

Performance of Serpent in CBC decryption and XTS with those module(s) loaded should be at near same level as software AES and Twofish (slightly faster or slower depending your exact CPU model).

Answer (score 0):

Also note that SSE2 code run by guest kernel in some VMs is much slower than on host kernel. I have experienced this with Oracle VirtualBox. So the results for Serpent on VM might not necessarily correlate with expected performance on actual host.